# How can I assign a value I get from a function to an integer in c?

Tags: c, function, integer, dice

I am doing a school assignment and don't know how to proceed without knowing how to do what I asked in the title. I was given code (by my prof) to run and print a dice roll (1-6).

```
void showDice (int num) {
     int diceRoll;
     srand(time(NULL));
     diceRoll = (rand() %6) +1;
     printf("%d\n", diceRoll);
     }
```

I know how to call it in the main function ( showDice(0); ) and that prints it out. But I need to know how to get it as an int (or another variable) so that I can add it to a total (or counter) variable.

Thanks

Comment: Since it's homework I won't do it for you, but your function needs to return something. That should point you in the right direction

Comment: The other alternative is to pass a pointer to `num` so that its value at the original address is updated. (i.e. `void showDice (int *num);`) Then at the end of the function `*num = diceRoll;`. You will then have the value of `diceRoll` in `num` back  in `main()`.

Comment: [srand() — why call it only once](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7343833/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply return it. Something like,

```
int showDice (int num) {
     int diceRoll;
     srand(time(NULL));
     diceRoll = (rand() % 6) + 1;
     printf("%d\n", diceRoll);
     return diceRoll;
}
```

Also, if you intended for `num` to be the number of sides,

```
int showDice (int num) {
     int diceRoll;
     srand(time(NULL));
     diceRoll = (rand() % num) + 1;
     printf("%d\n", diceRoll);
     return diceRoll;
}
```

Finally, you should only call `srand` once (at program startup).

Comment: If i were to just simply return it, how would I call it in the main function? Just like any other integer? So would I do something like showdice(0); printf("%d", diceRoll);

Comment: Something like `int roll = showDice(6); printf("%d\n", roll);`

Comment: would that give me a random number? or just 6?

Comment: A random number from 1-6. `showDice(20)` would be a [d20](http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/736x/d3/ca/c2/d3cac2ec56e311e7b1c724ce4fabc4c4.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

You can just return it (instead of printing it):

```
int rollDice(int num) {
     int diceRoll;
     srand(time(NULL));
     diceRoll = (rand() %6) +1;
     return diceRoll;
}
```

Removing some of the extraneous stuff, and if `num` is the number of sides:

```
int rollDice(int num) {
     srand(time(NULL));
     return (rand() % num) + 1;
}
```

Comment: The `srand` call should be (re)moved.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is change the type of the function to an int so that you can return  a value, and simply return diceRoll at the end of the function:

```
int showDice(int num) {
 int diceRoll;
 diceRoll = (rand() %6) +1;
 printf("%d\n", diceRoll);
 return (diceRoll);
}
```

Then you can call your function like this (note that srand should be called only once):

```
int main() {
 int rollDice;
 srand(time(NULL));
 rollDice = showDice(0);
}
```

Comment: The `srand` call should be (re)moved.